# How to migrate the posts from an old custom legacy blog to a new WordPress website?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system, migration

I have to migrate the posts of a very old custom legacy blog made in ASP (the posts are stored in a MySql table) into a new WordPress blog.

So I need your help to find the smartest solution to do it, I rule out the idea of ​​doing it manually because the number of posts that should be migrated is really high.

So looking this ER schema: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/97/WP3.8-ERD.png
I thought I could create a script that take a post from the post table of my old legacy blog and create a new record on the **wp_posts** wordpress post table of the new blog.

Is it a good solution or exist something better? A WP plugin on something like this?

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to take advantage of the WordPress Codex rather than importing directly into the tables. This will ensure that the IDs/relationships are generated correctly and that data is serialized as needed to the various tables. If you don't want to write custom code, the easiest way to do this would be to use a CSV import plugin - [there](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/) [are](https://wordpress.org/plugins/csv-importer/) [several](https://wordpress.org/plugins/xml-and-csv-import-in-article-content/) in the [WordPress Plugin Repository](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=csv) - but no particular recommendations.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say to me that its better using the Codex than import it directly into tables? The posts on the old blog have no comments and I think that the only relation is between post and user

Comment: @AndreaNobili - Inserting into the tables directly is certainly possible, but if you are new to WordPress and aren't familiar with all of the tables/columns and how they relate to each other it's easier to use a plugin that has already accounted for it. Not everything is directly imported for example, some meta data fields will be serialized, etc.

Comment: what do you mean that some metadata fields are serialized?